# Prove operator $(Tf)(x)=sin(x)\cdot f(x)$ is not compact

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Given the following operator in $L_2[0,1]$
$$(Tf)(x):=sin(x)\cdot f(x)$$

Prove or Disprove that the opertor is Compact.

I thought it is compact and used arzelà–Ascoli theorem, but apparently I am wrong.
I can't really find my mistake so if you can please help me it would be very much appreciated :)

**My attemp:**
To prove $T$ is compact it is enough to prove that it's image on the unit ball is relatively compact (remark from lecture). I will denote $B$ to be the unit ball, so I must show that $TB$ is relatively compact.

Using arzelà–Ascoli theorem it is enough to prove that $TB$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinous.

Note: arzelà–Ascoli theorem is for $C[0,1]$ but because the continouse function are dense in $L_2[0,1]$ I thought my use of the theorem is correct from this post: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126888/arzela-ascoli-theorem-in-lp0-1#:~:text=Let%20S%20be%20a%20subset,the%20set%20S%20is%20compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126888/arzela-ascoli-theorem-in-lp0-1#:%7E:text=Let%20S%20be%20a%20subset,the%20set%20S%20is%20compact).

Uniformly Bounded:
$$g\in TB \Rightarrow ||g||=||sin(x)f(x)||\leq ||f||\leq 1$$

Equicontinouse:
$$||g(x_1)-g(x_2)||=||Tf(x_1)-Tf(x_2)||\leq||T||f||x_1-x_2||\leq||x_1-x_2||\leq \epsilon$$

I showed in a different part that $||T||=1$ (and this is correct).

Thank you for the naswers :)

Comment: It is not compact. Take the spectral projection for $[\epsilon, +\infty)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ with $\sin^{-1}(\epsilon) < 1$, say. If it were compact this projection must be of finite rank, but in fact the projection has range $L^2([\sin^{-1}(\epsilon), 1])$, which is clearly infinite-dimensional.